# Php web service - results are not showing right on Android

Tags: php, android, utf-8

I have a PHP web service that control all my Database functions that gives responses in JSON Object
I'm encoding everything in the way to UTF-8 since I'm using Hebrew text - yet all my Hebrew text looses its spaces..

this is my http response code in Android:

```
private JSONObject getApiResponse(HttpResponse response) throws Exception
{
    //get response status line
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    //if statue line is ok - read the response and return it
    if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        entity.writeTo(out);
        out.close();                
        return new JSONObject(new String(out.toString().getBytes(),"UTF-8"));
    }
    return null;
}
```

this is my echo of reponse if php:

```
    $api = new api();
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">";
    echo utf8_encode($api -> processRequest()); //processRequest() always returns JSON object
```

- All data tables are in UTF 8
- PHP mysqli is set to UTF 8

this is example of response from the service:

```
{"events":[
{"Event_Code":"10212208",
 "Event_Name":"\u05de\u05e1\u05d9\u05d1\u05ea \u05e9\u05e9        
               \u05e9\u05e0\u05d9\u05dd                             
               \u05dc\u05d1\u05d0\u05e8\u05e7\u05d9",
  "Place":"\u05d4\u05e2\u05e6\u05de\u05d0\u05d5\u05ea 84 \u05d7\u05d9\u05e4\u05d4",
  "Start_Time":"2013-08-22 21:00:00",
  "End_Time":"2013-08-23  05:00:00",
  "Facebook_Id":"741688125",
   "User_Name":"Name"}]}
```

any idea ??

Comment: Am I blind or does `...\u05ea \u05e9...` have a space in it? Not sure what you're getting at...

Comment: it does... yet in my android screen those spaces are disapear

Comment: maybe should i wrap the content with some other encoding like URL ?

Comment: so it's probably not a php/json problem, since the spaces are present there. you'll have to look at your android-side display code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O.k. found the solution:

After reading Marc B comment, I've re-examined my code and found out that one of my text view combined between preset English word with a web service response in Hebrew..

This caused the view to be corrupted for some reason...